# Verificando se registro já existe no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou usando essa função no meu formulário mas estou com um problema.

Ele está validando o campo e não está incluindo no bd, mas a mensagem ao invés de dizer que o cliente já existe está dizendo que foi cadastrado com sucesso.

como corrigir isso?...se já existir no BD ele informa que o cliente já existe e se não existir ele informa que foi cadastrado?

meu cód está assim:

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj'");
if(@mysql_num_rows($search) > 0){
echo 'Esse Cliente já existe';
}else
// faz inserção

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO clientes (dia,mes,ano,data2,nome,fantasia,contato,fone,celular,email,cnpj,estadual,endereco,cep,bairro,cidade,estado,nf,desconto,obs) values
                                       ('$dia','$mes','$ano','$data2','$nome','$fantasia','$contato','$fone','$celular','$email','$cnpj','$estadual','$endereco','$cep','$bairro','$cidade','$estado','$nf','$desconto','$obs')");
   }
}

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
             alert("Registro Incluído com Sucesso!!!"); 
    </script>';

//Atualize a página
echo
'<script type="text/javascript">location.replace("clientes.php");</script>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj'");
if(@mysql_num_rows($search) > 0){
    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
             alert("Esse Cliente já existe"); 
        </script>
    ';
}else{

    // faz inserção

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO clientes (dia,mes,ano,data2,nome,fantasia,contato,fone,celular,email,cnpj,estadual,endereco,cep,bairro,cidade,estado,nf,desconto,obs) values('$dia','$mes','$ano','$data2','$nome','$fantasia','$contato','$fone','$celular','$email','$cnpj','$estadual','$endereco','$cep','$bairro','$cidade','$estado','$nf','$desconto','$obs')");

    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Registro Incluído com Sucesso!!!"); 
        </script>
    ';
}

//Atualize a página
echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.replace("clientes.php");</script>';
```

Comment: Valeu era isso mesmo, agora funcionou corretamente.....muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O trecho onde informa o sucesso da inclusão deve estar dentro do bloco do else.
No código da pergunta esse trecho está fora do else, por isso sempre mostra a mensagem.